# Smooth animated transition with valuelistenablebuilder

Tags: flutter, animation

I have designed a simple dashboard menu using valuelistenablebuilder which basically changes based on the selected icon.

Here's an example of how it looks

[image]

Whenever i click one of the dashboard buttons (cards inside a gridview), it updates the listennablevalue, and thus it leads to a similar view but the number of buttons (and the content within the button) changes.

however, there is no transition or animation as the basic material pageroute given the builder is just rebuilding the view.

Is there a way to add a smooth transition using this listener?

Comment: imho, its not clear what you want to achieve, you click one of cards and what should happen?

Comment: A transition from one screen to another rather than just instantly changing

Comment: so you need a [Hero](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations) widget

Comment: Was able to solve it using basic animations over the gridview! Thanks though!